# Etimología de "tiovivo"

Tags: etimología, sustantivos

**Tiovivo** aparece definido en el Diccionario de la Lengua por primera vez en 1925. La definición es prácticamente idéntica a la [actual](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZohyPyq):

> 1. m. Recreo de feria que consiste en varios asientos colocados en un círculo giratorio.

Aparece ya mencionado en 1880 en [**El traviato: zarzuela en dos actos**](https://books.google.es/books?id=pwUQAQAAIAAJ&q="tiovivo"), de Rafael Taboada y Mantilla y Juan Antonio Almela:

> Toma cuartos, y que te lleve Felipa al **Tiovivo**. (Vase precipitadamente en la misma direccion que tomó García.)

En [**Wikipedia**](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrusel#Origen_del_nombre_Tiovivo) encuentro:

> Joan Corominas recoge ... que podría referirse a la "viveza" del "tío" que lo inventó.​ Sin embargo, una anécdota muy extendida (que a algunas fuentes parece inverosímil)​ narra un suceso extraordinario que habría ocurrido en Madrid el 17 de julio de 1834, durante una epidemia de cólera: Esteban Fernández (el "Tío Esteban"), propietario de un carrusel infantil de cuatro caballos de juguete en el Paseo de las Delicias, enfermó y fue dado por muerto; al pasar su cortejo fúnebre precisamente por delante de su negocio, se oyó su voz gritar "¡Estoy vivo!, ¡estoy vivo!"; con lo que la gente pasó a llamar "el Tío Vivo" al propio Esteban y a su negocio, que siguió regentando.

¿Cuál es la etimología de "tiovivo"? ¿La señalada por Corominas? ¿La anécdota del "Tio Esteban"? ¿Alguna otra?

Comment: [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?tiovivo) se hace eco e la anécdota, fechándola en 1834 (y usando como referencia [Costumbres populares, de Sofía Tartilán](https://books.google.com/books?id=YSwNB28ADisC&pg=PA43&dq=Tio%20vivo&hl=es#v=onepage&q=Tio%20vivo&f=false)[1881]). Lo del brote de cólera en Madrid en 1834 [parece ser cierto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epidemias_de_c%C3%B3lera_en_Espa%C3%B1a#Primer_brote), pero la anécdota es demasiado dudosa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Encuentras casos anteriores si lo buscas por separado:

> Luego avanza la noche, las luces se van apagando; los vendedores, roncos de vocear y beber aguardiente, se esconden otra vez bajo los puestos como el caracol en su concha; las gitanas recogen los trebejos y soplan los candiles; los incansables caballos del tío vivo dejan de dar vueltas y cesa su acompañamiento de bombo y corneta de pistón; [...].
>
> Gustavo Adolfo Bécquer, "Artículos y escritos diversos", a1870 (España).

Pero más curiosos e inquietantes son los ejemplos que se encuentran en la hemeroteca a partir de 1837. En muchos artículos se habla de una persona a la que con frecuencia denominan "el supuesto tío vivo". A continuación algunos textos:

> Ayer nos regala la Gaceta de Madrid, el diario oficial del gobierno, un largo articulo titulado *crónica de Madrid*, mezcla informe de fruslerías, variedades y galicismos, en que danza el *tio Vivo* con su juego de sortija y su bombo; la temperatura, el aire, las funciones teatrales, el monumento del 2 de mayo [...].
>
> **El Eco del comercio.** 8/7/1837, n.º 1.165, página 4.
>
> ---
>
> Dicen que el señor gefe político ha descubierto una conspiración dirigida por el bombo de el Tío Vivo, dueño y señor de los juegos de columpio, situados cerca del cuartel de artillería; de cuyas resultas ha sido reducido á prisión (esto es, el bombo) y obligado á observar silencio perpetuo. Algunos creen que si hubiera sido posible, S. E. lo hace agarrotar. El Tío Vivo es miliciano nacional. El bombo no se sabe á que partido pertenece; pero él tocaba patrióticas.
>
> **El Mata-moscas (Madrid).** 14/7/1837, página 16.
>
> ---
>
> [...] cada uno sabe donde le aprieta el zapato, porque para su provecho ninguno es tonto; y sino, dígalo el supuesto tío Vivo, hombre tan próvido y tan sutil, que por temor de que se le escapen los músicos por el corbatin, con perdón sea dicho, los tiene en un tablado, puestos á la vergüenza y huyendo de la humedad, cubiertos con una red como si fuesen gansos ó patos, tocando que se las pelan agrias y sonatas.
>
> **El Panorama (Madrid).** 30/8/1838, n.º 23, página 20.
>
> ---
>
> [...] y por último, anoche bailé, de incógnito, con una Venus de Avapies, de las de mantilla caida y zagalejo en resumen, en el *salón del supuesto tio Vivo*.
>
> **El Correo nacional (Madrid).** 5/9/1838, página 4.

Estos artículos me resultan muy interesantes. Todo parece indicar que había un empresario conocido como *el tío vivo*, que regentaba un salón de baile con músicos que tocaban en directo, y ese salón tenía bastante fama en Madrid. Pero la cosa se pone más interesante:

> [...] el domingo anterior mientras la daifa ocupaba una silla en la máquina giratoria del supuestio tío vivo, la miraba un terne á lo zaino [...].
>
> **El Corresponsal (Madrid).** 7/7/1839, página 2.

¿Una máquina giratoria? Igual esta es la explicación de por qué el local tenía tanta fama. Pero en 1840 de repente me encuentro con esto y ya me descuadra:

> La máquina de caballos del supuesto tio Vivo, que tantos años ha estado colocada én
>   la pradera dé san Isidro, propia del escelentísimo señor conde de Bornos, se halla situada este año en el cerro de la derecha, por estar ocupado su antiguo sitio coa la
>   máquina del legítimo tío Vivo.
>
> **Diario de avisos de Madrid.** 15/5/1840, página 2.

Igual he estado interpretando mal los textos, y el salón no era un salón de baile, sino simplemente un local donde había un tiovivo, el tiovivo original del empresario llamado *el tío vivo*:

> Tampoco hablaremos del *tio Vivo* que con sus caballos de madera ha dado mas días de gloria á sus clientes, que otros á la patria con buenos caballos de carne y hueso, y ginetes de lanza en ristre embutidos en coraza y casco. Tres cuartos cuesta el dar dos vueltas en la máquina del *tío Vivo*, y por tan poca cosa seria una tacañería el dejar de columpiarse y hacer círculos concéntricos al compás de una murga que cuando se la ve tiene clarinete y fagot, pero cuando se la oye no aparece mas que el pom, pom, pom,
>   del bombo, y el chim, chim, chim, de los platillos tan destemplados que parecen collar de cascabeles ó sonajero de niños.
>
> *La Risa (Madrid).* 14/5/1843, página 6.

Pues yo diría que el salón del tío vivo era todo eso: un local donde había un tiovivo y que además la gente usaba para bailar al son de los músicos que tocaban en él.

Entiendo, pues, que el origen de la palabra *tiovivo* se debe únicamente a que el tiovivo original era el situado en el local de un empresario llamado *el tío vivo* (no sabemos si el supuesto o el legítimo), y la atracción era denominada "la máquina del tío vivo", de donde pasó sencillamente a "tiovivo". El por qué el empresario se llamaba "el tío vivo" es otra historia, que se escapa del ámbito de este sitio, aunque las primeras apariciones de "el tío vivo" en presa, hacia 1837, son compatibles con la anécdota mencionada en la pregunta, supuestamente ocurrida en 1834.